# programmatic where in clause for PredicateBuilder

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have extracted the relevant sections of the codebase to illustrate. Am really stuck on something potentially simple.

for information, in the database there is a one to many relationship between p and entity1.

```
predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<myType>();

.....

predicate = predicate.And(p => p.entity1.FirstOrDefault().id == 1 || p.entity1.FirstOrDefault().id == 2);
```

What I really need is to programmatically do the ( p.entity1.FirstOrDefault().id == 1 || p.entity1.FirstOrDefault().id == 2 )

forexample below

```
List<int> listOfId = new List<int>(){1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

predicate = predicate.And(p => p.entity1.id.wherein(listOfid);
```

Is there anyway this is possible please, it is quite critical to me.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `False` with `And`?

Answer (score 5):

Use `Contains` instead:

```
List<int> listOfId = new List<int>(){1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

predicate = predicate.And(p => listOfid.Contains(p.entity1.id));
```

Comment: Thank you for you reply. I made a very silly mistake before when I tried that, because the listOfid was the wrong type compared to the entity1.id. Its been a long day!! But thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case, the `Contains` method (as in @MarcinJuraszek's answer) is the way to go.

However, if you need to mix and match `And`s and `Or`s, you can do this:

```
predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<myType>();
//other clauses
.....
List<int> listOfId = new List<int>(){1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
var orClause = PredicateBuilder.True<MyType>();

foreach (var id in listOfId)
{
  orClause = orClause.Or(p => p.entity1.FirstOrDefault().id == id);
}

predicate = predicate.And(orClause);
```

(lifted from [here](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx))